# How to prove that $FC/FA + GC/GA= 0$ from this triangle problem?

Tags: proof-writing, triangles

In triangle $ABC$, a transversal line intersects $AB$, $BC$, $CA$ at $D,E,F$ respectively.

$BS$ intersects $AC$ at $G$, where $S$ is the intersection of $AE$ and $CD$.

[image]

How to prove that

> $$\frac{FC}{FA} + \frac{GC}{GA} = 0$$

Comment: $GC/GA$ can be expressed in terms of $CE$, $EB$, $BS$, $SA$, $AF$, and $FC$ using [Menelaus's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus'_theorem). And $FC/FA$ can be put in terms of $CE,BE,BS$, and $SA$ using [Ceva's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva's_theorem).

Comment: @ABC, now how can I prove it in an elegant way? thanks

Comment: @akusaja: ABC's way *is* the elegant way, although I'd use different segments. Since $D$, $E$, $F$ are collinear, Menelaus says $$\frac{AD}{DB}\frac{BE}{EC}\frac{CF}{FA}=-1 \quad \to \quad \frac{FC}{FA}=-\frac{CF}{FA}=\frac{DB}{AD}\frac{EC}{BE}$$ And since $AE$, $BG$, $CD$ concur at $S$, Ceva says $$\frac{AD}{DB}\frac{BE}{EC}\frac{CG}{GA}=1 \quad \to \quad \frac{GC}{GA} = -\frac{CG}{GA} = -\frac{DB}{DA}\frac{EC}{BE}=-\frac{FC}{FA}$$ Proofs don't get too much more elegant than that! :)

Comment: @Blue. Thanks for the solution. Now, should I write down the solution by ownself now? thanks :)